# XmlMapper deserializing XmlProperty as XmlElement

Tags: java, xml, spring, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I am writing an application that needs to make a POST request with XML. I have generated XML classes from XSD schema and am now trying to generate the body of said request with XmlMapper.

I have the following classes:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "header", propOrder = {
    "createdOn"
})
public class MessageHeader {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected MessageCreatedOn createdOn;

    ...
    ...
    ...
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "messageCreatedOn")
public class MessageCreatedOn {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "value", required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar value;
    
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

And the following XmlMapper configuration:

```
final XmlMapper objectMapper = XmlMapper.builder()
        .defaultUseWrapper(false)
        .build();
objectMapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"));
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);


String result = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(messageBase);
```

With dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.3</version>
</dependency>
```

I want result to be:

```
<header>
    <createdOn value="2021-08-18T14:06:14.493+03:00"/>
</header>
```

But the result is:

```
  <header>
    <createdOn>
      <value>2021-08-18T14:06:14.493+03:00</value>
    </createdOn>
  </header>
```

What should I change to get the `value` to be an attribute to `createdOn` element.

Comment: XmlMapper isn't JAXB. So those JAXB annotations aren't relevant anymore. Either use JAXB to deserialize or add the `JaxbAnnotationModule` to the `XmlMapper`, so it supports the JAXb annotations.

Comment: Thank you, can you form your response as an answer so I can select it as solution.

Comment: Also maybe you should change `@XmlType(name = "messageCreatedOn")` to `@XmlType(name = "createdOn")` in `MessageCreatedOn` class since the type name on the xml you posted is `createdOn`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using JAXB annotations as the metadata you need to instruct Jackson to use those. Else it will use the default, the Jackson annotations for XML or when absent, everything will become an element.

To enable JAXB annotation processing add the `JaxbAnnotationModule` to the `XmlMapper`. This lets Jackson use the JAXB annotation to provide the mapping metadata.

```java
final XmlMapper objectMapper = XmlMapper.builder()
        .defaultUseWrapper(false)
        .defaultDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"))
        .serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
        .addModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule())
        .build();
```

Also ideally your `XmlMapper` should be a singleton bean and not created each time you need it. Another note if you are using Spring, you should really be using a `RestTemplate` which handles the (un)marshalling for you.